# Pandas Dataframe: How to combine 2 dataframes but aggregate only 1 of the columns, while new rows get concatenated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, aggregate

Say I have df1

```
               prices    Type
name                      
ResidenceA     [1.0]     Condo
ResidenceB     [2.0]     Apartment
ResidenceC     [3.0]     Mansion
```

and df2

```
               prices    Type
name                      
ResidenceA     [2.0]     Condo
ResidenceD     [4.0]     Mansion
```

I want to merge df1 and df2 such that the result becomes

```
               prices         Type
name
ResidenceA     [1.0, 2.0]     Condo
ResidenceB     [2.0]          Apartment
ResidenceC     [3.0]          Mansion
ResidenceD     [4.0]          Mansion
```

In other words, since ResidenceA is in both dataframes, I want the resulting prices column to the an aggregation of both prices, but the other columns(Type) will just take the value from the first df. The other rows which do not clash would just be concatenated together. Is there a way to achieve this in one line? Or a neat way to do this would be good.

Comment: Please give the code (and the sample dataset used) to generate the two mentioned dataframes, so that I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
out=df1.append(df2).reset_index().groupby('name').agg({'prices':'sum','Type':'first'})
```

output of `out`:

```
           prices           Type
name        
ResidenceA  [1.0, 2.0]      Condo
ResidenceB  [2.0]           Apartment
ResidenceC  [3.0]           Mansion
ResidenceD  [4.0]           Mansion
```

Comment: `as_index` may not be required.

Comment: @Don'tAccept you are right sir...Thnx for noticing ***:)***